# How to keep javascript running in the background on android chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am creating a web application for smartphones that keeps throwing location information acquired by javascript to the API.
The problem is that javascript doesn't run when the browser goes to the background.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

I know it's better to create it with a native app, but it's not possible due to business problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to do something before the browser closes, you can use Service Workers.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is it possible to continue javascript processing even after the browser goes to the background?

Comment: Yes, with Service Workers you can run javascript in the background.

Comment: This won't work for what the OP wants. There is no navigator object inside of service workers. It is only available inside contexts that have access to a page's document object

Answer (score 0):

I have a WASM app with Javascript interop ([Github repo](https://github.com/POPWorldMedia/MLocker)) that plays music in the background continuously. There are possibly two reasons it will run:

- For sure, you need to make sure that you make battery use unrestricted for the browser in the Chrome app info. If you have it running as a web app with its own icon, make sure that "app" has the same setting (long press the icon, then tap info).
- You *may* need to run it as a web app, which is achieved by using it as a web app or PWA. Mozilla has docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps).

The thing that isn't great is that iOS very much doesn't like to let JS or media in web pages run in the background.